# structuring the vercel json file for flask app

Tags: python, flask, deployment, vercel

this is how my project structure looks like:

```
static
--styles.css
templates
--index.html
app.py
requirements.txt
```

How should I structure my vercel.json for online deployment? First I tried this:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      { "src": "app.py", "use": "@vercel/python" }
    ],
    "routes": [
      { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/app.py" }
    ]
  }
```

but the deployment was just stuck on "Build" forever. Then I tried this:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "app.py",
        "use": "@vercel/python"
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      { "handle": "filesystem" },
      {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/app.py"
      }
    ]
  }
```

but with this the deployment was "Queued" forever. What are the correct paths i should be using?

Edit:

My requirements.txt file has tensorflow & deepface.